# PHP - unable to execute my BASH script to launch my C++ binary

Tags: php, bash, apache, centos

## Part 1

In my `CentOS 7x`, i have my `C++` binary located in `/var/tmp/sip-dialer/reminder-call`.

Which is executed using following `BASH`

*reminder-call.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/tmp/sip-dialer
./redminder-call -P sip -u GokuPower -c 1234 -w reminder.myvoipserver.com -x "call003248181919;wakeupItsMorning;sleep3000;hangup"
```

On execute the whole setup works perfectly fine (Part 1).

## Part 2:

Now i need to call my BASH script from Android, iOS, Tizen and via other WebServices such as `https://cow:mow@myserver.com/run.php` .

So in my `ZF2, PHP` i have following:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh');
echo "executed";
?>
```

When i call the `PHP` to execute that `BASH` script it fails to execute with following:

```
/home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh: line 3: ./redminder-call: No such file or directory
```

What is happening? Manually BASH script works but involving PHP to execute the same thing is failing.

Comment: Have you checked your file permissions on `/home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh` to see if php has access to `/home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh` with privileges php has on execution?

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh; chmod +x /home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh;` is set, but still giving error php "No such file or directory"

Comment: can you do `ls -l /home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh` to see if your command has been applied to it?

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 142 Feb 22 10:19 /home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh`

Comment: You might need to set `chmod 777 /home/www/html/sip-phone/redminder-call` and `chmod +x /home/www/html/sip-phone/redminder-call`

Comment: YES - it was applied, still same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165634/discussion-between-cemal-and-yumyumyum).

Comment: is it a BUG in PHP? (it should not be so difficult cause all permission were given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the necessary permissions on `/home/www/html/sip-phone/redminder-call` as according to your output

`/home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh: line 3: ./redminder-call: No such file or directory`

the script

`/home/www/html/sip-phone/reminder-call.sh`

works but with the current privileges either the file

`/var/tmp/sip-dialer/redminder-call` is missing or doesn't have the necessary privileges.

To check file exists please do

`ls -l /var/tmp/sip-dialer/redminder-call`

and if it's there and check it's permissions.

If the permissions are valid (eg. `rwxrwxrwx`), check that the parent folder(s) has enough privilege to traverse and execute the file. More info on parent folder/file permissions are [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory)

Per your case

```
mv /var/tmp/sip-dialer /
chmod -R 777 /sip-dialer
chmod +x /sip-dialer/redminder-call
```

will do the trick. The problem is that `/var/` is not accessible as the current permissions for php is not enough to traverse it (unless you set +x or 777 to `/var` which is highly unrecommended for security purposes)